# flutter multi-platform user-agent

Tags: flutter, user-agent, flutter-http

I'm developing a multiplatform project with flutter for Android, iOS, and web. How can I get `user-agent` for adding to the header of the request?

I use `http` package for requests.
the sample user agent that I want:

Google sdk_gphone_x86, Android 11(30)

PostmanRuntime/7.26.8

Chrome, Mozilla, Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use device info plus [package](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

then use like below:

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}');  // e.g. "Moto G (4)"

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');  // e.g. "iPod7,1"

WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
print('Running on ${webBrowserInfo.userAgent}');  // e.g. "Mozilla/5.0 
(X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```

Comment: It should be wrong answer, We cannot get default user agent on Android/iOS by WebBrowserInfo. it is for flutter run on web